# Laravel Delete NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-4

delete request could not, and appears NotFoundHttpException, why ?

Route::

```
Route::delete('hapus_user/{id}',array('as' => 'delete_user', 'user' => 'UserController@destroy'));
```

Controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user3 = User::find($id);

    $user3->delete();

    return Redirect::to('user');
}
```

view :

```
<a href="<?php echo url('/user/hapus_user/'.$user->id_user); ?>">Hapus</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your route `user`. change this:

`'user' => 'UserController@destroy')`

To:

'uses' => 'UserController@destroy')

And you are using in your `url` the prefix '/user/' before the `url` of the `route` while it doesn't exist in the `route` configuration. Change this:

`<a href="<?php echo url('/user/hapus_user/'.$user->id_user); ?>">Hapus</a>`

To:

`<a href="<?php echo url('/hapus_user/'.$user->id_user); ?>">Hapus</a>`

Hope this helps.